# U-net segment wrongly the image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i used this implementation of `u-net model` to segment tumors in medical images, after training and evaluating the model , the predicted masks are all black, could anyone tell me what's the problem, here's the code

```
def adjustData(img,mask,flag_multi_class,num_class):
    if(flag_multi_class):
        img = img / 255
        mask = mask[:,:,:,0] if(len(mask.shape) == 4) else mask[:,:,0]
        new_mask = np.zeros(mask.shape + (num_class,))
        for i in range(num_class):
            #for one pixel in the image, find the class in mask and convert it into one-hot vector
            #index = np.where(mask == i)
            #index_mask = (index[0],index[1],index[2],np.zeros(len(index[0]),dtype = np.int64) + i) if (len(mask.shape) == 4) else (index[0],index[1],np.zeros(len(index[0]),dtype = np.int64) + i)
            #new_mask[index_mask] = 1
            new_mask[mask == i,i] = 1
        new_mask = np.reshape(new_mask,(new_mask.shape[0],new_mask.shape[1]*new_mask.shape[2],new_mask.shape[3])) if flag_multi_class else np.reshape(new_mask,(new_mask.shape[0]*new_mask.shape[1],new_mask.shape[2]))
        mask = new_mask
    elif(np.max(img) > 1):
        img = img / 255
        mask = mask /255
        mask[mask > 0.5] = 1
        mask[mask <= 0.5] = 0
    return (img,mask)



def trainGenerator(batch_size,train_path,image_folder,mask_folder,aug_dict,image_color_mode = "grayscale",
                    mask_color_mode = "grayscale",image_save_prefix  = "image",mask_save_prefix  = "mask",
                    flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2,save_to_dir = None,target_size = (256,256),seed = 1):
    '''
    can generate image and mask at the same time
    use the same seed for image_datagen and mask_datagen to ensure the transformation for image and mask is the same
    if you want to visualize the results of generator, set save_to_dir = "your path"
    '''
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        classes = [image_folder],
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = image_color_mode,
        target_size = target_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
        save_prefix  = image_save_prefix,
        seed = seed)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        classes = [mask_folder],
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = mask_color_mode,
        target_size = target_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        save_to_dir = save_to_dir,
        save_prefix  = mask_save_prefix,
        seed = seed)
    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
    for (img,mask) in train_generator:
        img,mask = adjustData(img,mask,flag_multi_class,num_class)
        yield (img,mask)



def testGenerator(test_path,num_image = 30,target_size = (256,256),flag_multi_class = False,as_gray = True):
    for i in range(num_image):
        img = io.imread(os.path.join(test_path,"%d.png"%i),as_gray = as_gray)
        img = img / 255
        img = trans.resize(img,target_size)
        img = np.reshape(img,img.shape+(1,)) if (not flag_multi_class) else img
        img = np.reshape(img,(1,)+img.shape)
        yield img


def geneTrainNpy(image_path,mask_path,flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2,image_prefix = "image",mask_prefix = "mask",image_as_gray = True,mask_as_gray = True):
    image_name_arr = glob.glob(os.path.join(image_path,"%s*.png"%image_prefix))
    image_arr = []
    mask_arr = []
    for index,item in enumerate(image_name_arr):
        img = io.imread(item,as_gray = image_as_gray)
        img = np.reshape(img,img.shape + (1,)) if image_as_gray else img
        mask = io.imread(item.replace(image_path,mask_path).replace(image_prefix,mask_prefix),as_gray = mask_as_gray)
        mask = np.reshape(mask,mask.shape + (1,)) if mask_as_gray else mask
        img,mask = adjustData(img,mask,flag_multi_class,num_class)
        image_arr.append(img)
        mask_arr.append(mask)
    image_arr = np.array(image_arr)
    mask_arr = np.array(mask_arr)
    return image_arr,mask_arr


def labelVisualize(num_class,color_dict,img):
    img = img[:,:,0] if len(img.shape) == 3 else img
    img_out = np.zeros(img.shape + (3,))
    for i in range(num_class):
        img_out[img == i,:] = color_dict[i]
    return img_out / 255



def saveResult(save_path,npyfile,flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2):
    for i,item in enumerate(npyfile):
        img = labelVisualize(num_class,COLOR_DICT,item) if flag_multi_class else item[:,:,0]
        io.imsave(os.path.join(save_path,"%d_predict.png"%i),img)

data_gen_args = dict()
myGene = trainGenerator(2,'/content/drive/My Drive/Memoire-Mastere/dataset-unet/train','images','masks',data_gen_args,save_to_dir =None)

def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model

model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=3,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])


testGene = testGenerator("/content/drive/MyDrive/Memoire-Mastere/dataset-unet/test/rtdpng")
model = unet()
model.load_weights("unet_membrane.hdf5")
results = model.predict_generator(testGene,20,verbose=1)
saveResult("/content/drive/MyDrive/Memoire-Mastere/dataset-unet/test/rtdpng",results)
```

here's one of the predicted mask images that i got:

[image: 1]

and here is an example of the original images

[image: 2]

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, and you've got a lot of code present. Please add in some information about things you've tried, and try to narrow the amount of code presented to the specific cause.
Things to try: Swap for different training data, swap for a different model, modify various parameters. Please also describe the training data: number of images, how they're labelled, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: in the training set there's 100 images+100 masks, and in the test set there's 20 images the images are greyscale, i tried to modify the training set, increase the number of epochs and changing the  value of steps per epochs  but i got the same result(always the black predicted images),

Comment: 100 items in the training set seems really small for a 9-layer network. Try training it to recognize locate simple shapes in the image, or to find the edges of randomly-cropped complex images which have the same dimensions as your input. You should be able to procedurally generate thousands of such examples.  If you can train on such data, your issue is that you don't have enough training data. You can also covert the masks to an array of floats: Are they the exact same value every time, or are there differences between outputs? Do some output masks vary slightly?

Comment: Also, are you working from sample mask-generating code, a tutorial, or a how-to guide?  If so, add those links.

Comment: i added images to the database now i have 270 and after data augmentation i have more than 1000 images, after training i got images with segmented region, but they are not true segmentation. i can't add more images, how can i change the model architecture, (decrease the number of layers) can i just delete a layer without changing the next layer

Comment: actually am using the implementation of  [https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet]

Comment: What is the expected output mask for your sample input training image?
Also, the GitHub link you provided is not publicly visible.

Comment: the expected output mask of my image is a mask for the tumor region, it's a brain tumor segmentation task, for the github link i don't know how to do it, it's visible to me

Comment: You can post a mask output by your network, but not the mask you use during training? Both must be in the same file format for the network to work.

Comment: please see my post, i posted the predict mask output by my network (from the test set)

Comment: The only mask you've posted has a problem. That problem is the point of your post. 
Please post a CORRECT mask.
If you don't have a correct mask, you cannot train the network. If you have a correct mask but cannot post it, then it's not in the same format as the masks produced by your network - which is a problem that you'll need to fix in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is black as in your last layer you are using only one filter.

```
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
```

This is the reason, the network only outputs only black.

In the segmentation task, each pixel is classified into a class. So here as you have used one, all the pixel has been classified to only one class.

Depending upon how many classes you have, you will have to update the filter. If you are expecting your mask with three different classes then update the code as below. Also, demonstrating the same with a picture.

```
conv10 = Conv2D(3, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
```

[image]

Look at the following [reading](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation), it will help you understand better.

Comment: the problem was solved when i deleted this layer ` conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9) ` also i changed the learning rate to 3e-5